# A Python Script Keeps Stumbling Over in Excel

Tags: python, excel, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I'm looking for some help and guidance with a Python script as I am at my wits end with trying to get it to work.

For some context, every morning an email comes in from a specified email address with an Excel attachment. My job requires me to open the Excel attachment, remove the first row and all the blank rows - then save the attachment in a new location with a new filename.

Last week the script was 99% working, it did everything but would corrupt the Excel file in the process - throwing the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwess.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZIZF.png

To make matters worse, I took a week or so break from this script as I couldn't figure it out - and although no code has changed, the script is now throwing the following error:

"*line 112, in  email_items = shared_inbox.Items.Restrict(
File "<COMObject >", line 2, in Restrict
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Condition is not valid.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)*"

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import openpyxl

# 'medocc_path' is a variable containing the path of the MedOCC shared drive folder.
medocc_path = r"S:\File\Path"

# Get the previous day's date in the format yyyymmdd which is required for
# job 'MFT_DW - MedOCC', represented by variable {yesterday}.
yesterday = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Define a function to check for Excel attachments to remove the first row and all blank rows.
def process_excel_attachment(file_path):
    # Save the attachment to a temporary folder
    temp_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "temp")
    if not os.path.exists(temp_path):
        os.makedirs(temp_path)
    temp_file = os.path.join(temp_path, os.path.basename(file_path))
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    with open(temp_file, "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)

    # Open the workbook and process it
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(temp_file)
    sheet = workbook.active

    # Remove first row and blank rows
    sheet.delete_rows(1)
    counter = 0  # Initialize counter to zero
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
            sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)
            # Subtract 1 from counter to account for deleted row
            counter -= 1

    # Remove all filters and freezed rows
    sheet.auto_filter.ref = None
    sheet.freeze_panes = None

    # Apply filter and freeze to the first row
    first_row = next(sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1))
    for cell in first_row:
        if cell.value:
            col_letter = cell.column_letter
            values = [
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=cell.column).value
                for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1)
                if sheet.cell(row=row, column=cell.column).value
            ]
            sheet.auto_filter.ref = f"{col_letter}1:{col_letter}{sheet.max_row}"
            sheet.auto_filter.add_filter_column(cell.col_idx, values)
            sheet.column_dimensions[cell.column_letter].auto_size = True
            sheet.freeze_panes = "A2"

    # Remove all blank rows
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        if all(cell.value is None for cell in row):
            sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)

    # Remove the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file)

    # Return the processed workbook
    return workbook


# Connect to Outlook
print("Connecting to Outlook...")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application.16").GetNamespace("MAPI")

# Open the shared inbox
print("Opening inbox...")
try:
    shared_inbox = outlook.Folders.Item(
        "TEAM"
    ).Folders.Item("Inbox")
    print("Successfully connected to shared inbox")
except:
    print("Error: Failed to connect to shared inbox")

# Search for emails from specific senders in the past 5 days
email_senders = [
    "email1@email.net",
    "email2@email.net",
    "email3@email.net",
]

# Define a time frame of the past 5 days
start_time = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)).strftime(
    "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
)
end_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")

# Update date format to match Outlook's format
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")

# Check if the medocc_path folder exists
if not os.path.exists(medocc_path):
    print(f"Error: The folder {medocc_path} does not exist.")
    exit()

# Define a flag to check if an email with attachment has been found
email_with_attachment_found = False

for sender in email_senders:
    print(f"Searching for emails from sender '{sender}' in the past 5 days...")

    # Get the email items from the past 5 days
    email_items = shared_inbox.Items.Restrict(
        f"[ReceivedTime] >= '{start_time}' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '{end_time}' AND ([SenderName] = 'Person1' OR [SenderName] = 'Person2' OR [SenderName] = 'Person3') AND (SUBJECT LIKE '%type 3%')"
    )


    # Sort the email items by ReceivedTime in descending order
    email_items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

    email_item = None  # default value

    # Process only the most recent email
    if len(email_items) > 0:
        email_item = email_items[0]
        print("Processing email with subject:", email_item.Subject)

    # Set the flag to True if an email with attachment has been found
    if email_item.Attachments is not None and email_item.Attachments.Count > 0:
        email_with_attachment_found = True

        # Iterate over the attachments
        for attachment in email_item.Attachments:
            if attachment.FileName.endswith(".xlsx"):
                print(
                    "Found Excel attachment with filename",
                    attachment.FileName,
                    "from sender",
                    sender,
                    "with subject:",
                    email_item.Subject,
                )

                # Save the attachment temporarily...
                temp_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "temp")
                if not os.path.exists(temp_path):
                    os.makedirs(temp_path)

                temp_file = os.path.join(temp_path, attachment.FileName)
                attachment.SaveAsFile(temp_file)

                # Process the attachment
                workbook = process_excel_attachment(temp_file)

                # Remove the temporary file
                if os.path.exists(temp_file):
                    os.remove(temp_file)

                # Save the processed workbook to the MedOCC folder
                new_file_name = os.path.join(medocc_path, f"MedOCC_{yesterday}.xlsx")
                workbook.save(new_file_name)

                # Check if the file has been saved in the path
                if os.path.exists(new_file_name):
                    print("Attachment processed and saved as:", new_file_name)
                else:
                    print(
                        "Error: The file could not be saved in the folder", medocc_path
                    )

    # Print a message if no email with attachment is found from the current sender
    if not email_with_attachment_found:
        print(
            f"No emails found from sender '{sender}' with the specified attachment file name in the past 5 days."
        )
    else:
        email_with_attachment_found = False
else:
    print("No email found.")
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone with a few spare moments could review the script / provide clarity on the errors I'm facing.

I tried prompting ChatGPT for answers but none of them seemed to fix the script.

Comment: `for row in sheet.iter_rows():` ... `sheet.delete_rows(row[0].row)`, You are iterating over a generator (i.e. lazily evaluated) and at the same time removing stuff from the underlying data structure. Can't say if that's your (or your only) issue, but that can't go well.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that the date-time comparison string is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function (or its equivalent in your programming language). The following VBA example creates a Jet filter to find all contacts that have been modified before June 12, 2022 at 3:30 P.M local time:

```
criteria = "[LastModificationTime] < '" _ 
         & Format$("6/12/2022 3:30PM","General Date") & "'"
```

In you search criteria line the last check looks unknown:

```
 # Get the email items from the past 5 days
    email_items = shared_inbox.Items.Restrict(
        f"[ReceivedTime] >= '{start_time}' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '{end_time}' AND ([SenderName] = 'Person1' OR [SenderName] = 'Person2' OR [SenderName] = 'Person3') AND (SUBJECT LIKE '%type 3%')"
    )
```

If you need to include the `Subject` property into the search criteria you need to use square brackets:

```
 # Get the email items from the past 5 days
    email_items = shared_inbox.Items.Restrict(
        f"[ReceivedTime] >= '{start_time}' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '{end_time}' AND ([SenderName] = 'Person1' OR [SenderName] = 'Person2' OR [SenderName] = 'Person3') AND ([Subject] = '%type 3%')"
    )
```

In a Jet query, you can only perform phrase-matching on a keywords property. You cannot perform starts-with or substring matching with a Jet query. To overcome the limitations of keywords restrictions using the Jet query syntax, use DASL syntax which allows starts-with or substring restrictions. For example:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'question'"
```

So, if you want to include a phrase match search into your search string you need to re-write it using the DASL syntax like shown above.

---

Second, to get the `Inbox` folder like shown below:

```
shared_inbox = outlook.Folders.Item(
        "TEAM"
    ).Folders.Item("Inbox")
```

Use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Namespace` class instead. The method returns a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Calendar folder for the user who is currently logged on.

Also you may find the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method helpful. It returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.